# People Search not updating Job Title?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, people-search

I ran an incremental `User Profile Synchronization` which correctly updated the user's Job Title (verified in `Manage User Profiles`). I then ran an incremental search crawl on the MySite (sps3://mysite). However, People Search results still show the old job title. I then ran a *full* search crawl on the MySite and the old job title is still shown.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at the crawl logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly, I was crawling the old SharePoint 2010 MySite, not the new 2013 MySite.